# Prolog Recursion in lists, last but one element

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

The question is to find the last but one character in a list, e.g.

```
?- last_but_one(X, [a,b,c,d]).
X = c.
```

My code is:

```
last_but_one(X, [X,_]).
last_but_one(X, [_|T]) :- last_but_one(X, T).
```

and the code they gave is:

```
last_but_one(X, [X,_]).
last_but_one(X, [_,Y|Ys]) :- last_but_one(X, [Y|Ys]).
```

When I was studying Haskell, I can recall that when questions asked for the 2nd, 3rd, or nth character in some list, the structure was the same as the answer that's been supplied, so I know writing it the way they've written it has some significance. But I still seem to get correct answers with the way I have written it.

Is the way I have written it wrong? Is the code that the guys who made the answer wrote better—and if so, how?

Comment: And a third option for the second clause: `last_but_one(X, [_,Y,Z|T]) :- last_but_ont(X, [Y,Z|T]).` which enforces that the 2nd argument be a list of at least 3 elements, making the constraints a little more precise. :)

Comment: I don't agree with at least 3 - 2 elements is fine and there should still be a last but one element in this case. Why did you think that the constraint of at least 3 elements is particularly important?

Comment: I'm only saying it is slightly more efficient. You already have `last_but_one(X, [X,_]).` So to have another clause that matches a two-element list as the second argument is redundant.

Comment: @false. Very attentive. It must have escaped me. Thx!

Comment: @repeat: It made the answers look not on topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original version is much simpler to read. In particular, the recursive rule reads - reading it right-to-left

```
last_but_one(X, [_|T]) :- last_but_one(X, T).
                          ^^^^^^^^^^
                              provided X is the lbo-element in T

                       ^^  then, it follows, that (that's an arrow!)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      X is also the lbo-element of T with one more element
```

In other words: If you have already an lbo-element in a given list `T`, then you can construct new lists with any further elements in front that also have the very same lbo-element.

One might debate which version is preferable as to efficiency. If you are really into that, rather take:

```
last_but_one_f1(E, Es) :-
   Es = [_,_|Xs],
   xs_es_lbo(Xs, Es, E).

xs_es_lbo([], [E|_], E).
xs_es_lbo([_|Xs], [_|Es], E) :-
   xs_es_lbo(Xs, Es, E).
```

or even:

```
last_but_one_f2(E, [F,G|Es]) :-
    es_f_g(Es, F, G, E).

es_f_g([], E, _, E).
es_f_g([G|Es], _, F, E) :-
   es_f_g(Es, F, G, E).
```

Never forget general testing:

```
?- last_but_one(X, Es).
   Es = [X,_A]
;  Es = [_A,X,_B]
;  Es = [_A,_B,X,_C]
;  Es = [_A,_B,_C,X,_D]
;  Es = [_A,_B,_C,_D,X,_E]
;  Es = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,X,_F]
;  false.
```

And here are some benchmarks on my olde labtop:

```
          SICStus     SWI
          4.3.2     7.3.20-1
    --------------+----------+--------
    you   0.850s  |   3.616s |  4.25×
    they  0.900s  |  16.481s | 18.31×
    f1    0.160s  |   1.625s | 10.16×
    f2    0.090s  |   1.449s | 16.10×
    mat   0.880s  |   4.390s |  4.99×
    dcg   3.670s  |   7.896s |  2.15×
    dcgx  1.000s  |   7.885s |  7.89×
    ap    1.200s  |   4.669s |  3.89×
```

The reason for the big difference is that both `f1` and `f2` run purely determinate without any creation of a choicepoint.

Using

```
bench_last :-
   \+ ( length(Ls, 10000000),
        member(M, [you,they,f1,f2,mat,dcg,dcgx,ap]), write(M), write(' '),
        atom_concat(last_but_one_,M,P), \+ time(call(P,L,Ls))
   ).
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, that's really helpful :)

Comment: Hmm, looking back at this, that's really interesting why SWI is so slow. I used it a long time back and don't remember it being quite this slow. 16.481s for their query?? That's insane.

Comment: Well `they` read two elements and then recreate one element. At least, that' what happens in SWI.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach using DCGs.  I think that this solution is much more "graphical", but it seems quite slow in SICStus:

```
last_but_one_dcg(L, Ls) :-
   phrase( ( ..., [L,_] ), Ls).

... --> [].
... --> [_], ... .
```

So we describe how a list must look like such that it has a last-but-one element. It looks like this: Anything (`...`) in front, and then two elements at the end.

It gets a bit faster by expanding `phrase/2`. Note that the expansion itself is no longer a conforming program.

```
last_but_one_dcgx(L, Ls) :-
   ...(Ls, Ls2),
   Ls2 = [L,_].
```

Answer (score 2):

I would say both answers are just as good and I would probably have written it the way you did. What they do in the second solution is that they check, before the recursive call, that the second element is not a empty list ([]). If you trace the two different solutions on the following query: `last_but_one(X,[b]).`

You'll see that both give the same answer (false), but the second solution takes shorter amount of steps since it returns false before the recursive call is made.

Comment: Ah, got you. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @false that your own version is simpler to read.

Personally, I find using a DCG (see [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)) even easier:

```
last_but_one(X) --> [X,_].
last_but_one(X) -->
    [_],
    last_but_one(X).
```

As interface predicate, you can use:

```
last_but_one(L, Ls) :-
    phrase(last_but_one(L), Ls).
```

I now would like to add some actual timings.

We have 3 versions for comparison:

1. the DCG version, which I call `last_but_one//1`
2. your own version, which I call `last_but_one_you/2`
3. their version, which I call `last_but_one_they/2`.

The test case consists of finding the penultimate element of a list with ten million elements.

We have:

```
?- length(Ls, 10_000_000), time(last_but_one(L, Ls)), false.
9,999,999 inferences, 1.400 CPU in 1.400 seconds (100% CPU, 7141982 Lips)

?- length(Ls, 10_000_000), time(last_but_one_you(L, Ls)), false.
9,999,998 inferences, 1.383 CPU in 1.383 seconds (100% CPU, 7229930 Lips)

?- length(Ls, 10_000_000), time(last_but_one_they(L, Ls)), false.
9,999,998 inferences, 5.566 CPU in 5.566 seconds (100% CPU, 1796684 Lips)
```

This shows that not only is the version that they provided much harder to read, it is also **by far the slowest** for this benchmark.

Always aim for elegance and readability first. Very often, you also obtain a fast version if you follow this principle.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the timings information, thats helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

Here are more ways how you *could* do it. 
I wouldn't recommend actually using any of the following methods, but IMO they are interesting as they give a different view on the other codes and on the Prolog library provided by the respective Prolog processors:

In the first three variants, we delegate the "recursive part" to built-in / library predicates:

```
last_but_one_append(X,Es) :-
   append(_, [X,_], Es).

:- use_module(library(lists)).
last_but_one_reverse(X, Es) :-
   reverse(Es, [_,X|_]).

last_but_one_rev(X, Es) :-  
   rev(Es, [_,X|_]).           % (SICStus only)
```

Alternatively, we could use vanilla home-brewed `myappend/3` and `myreverse/2`:

```
myappend([], Bs, Bs).
myappend([A|As], Bs, [A|Cs]) :-
   myappend(As, Bs, Cs).

last_but_one_myappend(X, Es) :-
   myappend(_, [X,_], Es).

myreverse(Es, Fs) :-
   same_length(Es, Fs),        % for universal termination in mode (-,+)
   myreverse_(Es, Fs, []).

myreverse_([], Fs, Fs).
myreverse_([E|Es], Fs, Fs0) :-
   myreverse_(Es, Fs, [E|Fs0]).

last_but_one_myreverse(X, Es) :-
   myreverse(Es, [_,X|_]).
```

Let's run the experiments<sup>1</sup>!

```
bench_last :-
   \+ ( length(Ls, 10000000),
        member(M, [you,they,f1,f2,mat,dcg,dcgx,ap,
                   append,reverse,rev,
                   myappend,myreverse]),
        write(M), write(' '),
        atom_concat(last_but_one_,M,P),
        \+ time(call(P,_L,Ls))
   ).
```

Here are the runtimes<sup>2</sup> using SICStus Prolog and SWI-Prolog<sup>3,4</sup>:

```
               SICStus | SICStus | SWI    |
                 4.3.2 |   4.3.3 | 7.3.20 |
    -------------------+---------+--------|
    you          0.26s |   0.10s |  0.83s |  3.1×  8.3×
    they         0.27s |   0.12s |  1.03s |  3.8×  8.5×
    f1           0.04s |   0.02s |  0.43s | 10.8× 21.5×
    f2           0.02s |   0.02s |  0.37s | 18.5× 18.5×
    mat          0.26s |   0.11s |  1.02s |  3.9×  9.0×
    dcg          1.06s |   0.77s |  1.47s |  1.3×  1.9×
    dcgx         0.31s |   0.17s |  0.97s |  3.1×  5.7×
    ap           0.23s |   0.11s |  0.42s |  1.8×  3.8×
    append       1.50s |   1.13s |  1.57s |  1.0×  1.3×
    reverse      0.36s |   0.32s |  1.02s |  2.8×  3.1×
    rev          0.04s |   0.04s |  --"-- | 25.6× 25.6×
    myappend     0.48s |   0.33s |  1.56s |  3.2×  4.7×
    myreverse    0.27s |   0.26s |  1.11s |  4.1×  4.2×
```

---

#### Edit: Added SICStus Prolog 4.3.3 benchmarking data

Very impressive! In the SICStus/SWI speedup column, differences > 10% got **bold-faced**.

---

<sup>**Footnote 1**: All measurements shown in this answer were obtained on an Intel 
[Haswell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haswell_%28microarchitecture%29) processor 
[Core i7-4700MQ](http://ark.intel.com/products/75117/Intel-Core-i7-4700MQ-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_40-GHz).


**Footnote 2**: `rev/2` is offered by SICStus—but not by SWI. We compare the fastest "reverse" library predicate.


**Footnote 3**: The SWI command-line option `-G1G` was required to prevent `Out of global stack` errors.


**Footnote 4**: Also, the SWI command-line option `-O` (optimize) was tried, but did not yield *any* improvement.</sup>

Comment: Impressive speedups by 4.3.3. What is the pattern here? Looks like programs creating choice points profit a lot.

Answer (score 1):

*another solution :*

- firstly, the list must be of length >= 2,
- also the last length element of the list = 1

*code :*

```
last_but_one(R,[X|Rest]):-
   (  Rest=[_], R=X
   ;  last_but_one(R,Rest)
   ).
```

*Test :*

```
| ?- last_but_one(Elem,List).
List = [Elem,_A] ? ;
List = [_A,Elem,_B] ? ;
List = [_A,_B,Elem,_C] ? ;
List = [_A,_B,_C,Elem,_D] ? ;
List = [_A,_B,_C,_D,Elem,_E] ? ;
List = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,Elem,_F] ? ;
List = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F,Elem,_G] ? ;
List = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G,Elem,_H] ? 
yes
```

*Hope this idea help you*

Comment: Your definition produces exactly one answer! - also note the different  argument order.

Comment: @false sorry  I don't understand the first part of your point

Comment: The query `last_but_one(Elem, List)` produces exactly one answer and not infinitely many. The  `->` in your definition is responsible for this.

Comment: @false thank you, I test it with ',' but when I copy code over here I change it to  `->'

Comment: The time is not large enough - probably you have a typo

Comment: @false  **with , ** :   `?- length(Ls, 10_000_000), time(last_but_one(L, Ls)), false.
% 9,999,998 inferences, 0.578 CPU in 0.573 seconds (101% CPU, 17297294 Lips)
% 10 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
false.`       **with ->** : `?- length(Ls, 10_000_000), time(last_but_one(L, Ls)), false.
% 10,000,007 inferences, 0.594 CPU in 0.590 seconds (101% CPU, 16842117 Lips)
false.` !

Comment: I  test  the first example ; `last_but_one(R,[X|Rest]):-  Rest=[_]->R=X; last_but_one(R,Rest).`  and I got this result ; `?- length(Ls, 10_000_000), time(last_but_one(L, Ls)), false.
% 10,000,007 inferences, 0.594 CPU in 0.595 seconds (100% CPU, 16842117 Lips)
false.`

Comment: where is the best solution ?

Comment: That depends what you want. Readability or speed.

Comment: I think speed  with `->`

Comment: And: The speed of both is exactly the same. See my answer which includes your version (`ap`), too