# Need to remove last but one element in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I have been trying to do different things in prolog and want to remove the last but one element and i don't know how.

This is my code:

```
without(X,[X,_],[]).
without(X,[K|Xs],[K|AlmoustLast]) :-
    without(X,Xs,AlmoustLast).
```

And this is what i receive when compiling.

```
?-  without(X,[1,2,3,4,5],A).
X = 4,
A = [1, 2, 3] .
```

When the answear I am trying to achieve is **A = [1,2,3,5].**

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36685680/772868).

Comment: Look at `without(1,[1,2],L)`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost right with

```
without(X,[X,_],[]).
without(X,[K|Xs],[K|AlmoustLast]) :-
    without(X,Xs,AlmoustLast).
```

In fact, the following

```
without(X,[X,Y],[Y]).
without(X,[K|Xs],[K|AlmostLast]) :-
    without(X,Xs,AlmostLast).
```

gives you

```
?- without(X,[1,2,3,4,5],A).

A = [1,2,3,5]
X = 4
```

Comment: Thanks! In fact i use the same thing(sumf(X,Y,[X,Y],_).) when i calculated the sum of the last 2 numbers but i didn't think of using it here...

Answer (score 2):

Rafalon gave the corrected result, to which I'll provide an explanation.

You're base case rule logic is flawed:

```
without(X,[X,_],[]).
```

Here you're saying that if you remove the last but one from `[X,_]`, then you get element `X` and list `[]`, but that doesn't sound logical, does it? What happened to `_`? You're using an anonymous variable here implying you don't care about it, but you really do care! As Rafalon indicates, this rule should be:

```
without(X, [X,Y], [Y]).
```

So that the last but one of the list `[X, Y]` gives you the element `X` and the list `[Y]`.

Comment: That's true, I could and I should have explained it. +1 for your explanation.