# Why is this "last_element" prolog predicate more optimal?

Tags: prolog

We want to check if an element appears in the last of a list, we have this prolog program which is obvious for me:

```
last(X,[X]).
last(X,[_|L]):-
    last(X,L).
```

But our teacher gave us another solution, and he said that it is more optimal, there is it:

```
last(X,[X]).
last(X,[_,Y|L]):-
    last(X,[Y|L]).
```

Why is the second solution more optimal?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36701487/772868).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so theoretically he is right.
With his method we won't check last empty element that is always contained in list.
It's easy to check with 2 things, the first one is `time` function, and the other one is `trace`. Here are listings (lastX is your teacher version, and lastY is yours):

```
?- time(lastY(5,[1,2,3,4,5])).
% 5 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (86% CPU, 1743983 Lips)
true

?- time(lastX(5,[1,2,3,4,5])).
% 4 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (86% CPU, 194203 Lips)
true .

?- time(lastX(6,[1,2,3,4,5])).
% 6 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (87% CPU, 279382 Lips)
false.

?- time(lastY(6,[1,2,3,4,5])).
% 7 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (85% CPU, 335008 Lips)
false.

[trace]  ?- lastY(6,[1,2,3,4,5]).
   Call: (7) lastY(6, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) ? Unknown option (h for help)
   Call: (7) lastY(6, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) ? creep
   Call: (8) lastY(6, [2, 3, 4, 5]) ? creep
   Call: (9) lastY(6, [3, 4, 5]) ? creep
   Call: (10) lastY(6, [4, 5]) ? creep
   Call: (11) lastY(6, [5]) ? creep
   Call: (12) lastY(6, []) ? creep
   Fail: (12) lastY(6, []) ? creep
   Fail: (11) lastY(6, [5]) ? creep
   Fail: (10) lastY(6, [4, 5]) ? creep
   Fail: (9) lastY(6, [3, 4, 5]) ? creep
   Fail: (8) lastY(6, [2, 3, 4, 5]) ? creep
   Fail: (7) lastY(6, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) ? creep
false.

[trace]  ?- lastX(6,[1,2,3,4,5]).
   Call: (7) lastX(6, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) ? creep
   Call: (8) lastX(6, [2, 3, 4, 5]) ? creep
   Call: (9) lastX(6, [3, 4, 5]) ? creep
   Call: (10) lastX(6, [4, 5]) ? creep
   Call: (11) lastX(6, [5]) ? creep
   Fail: (11) lastX(6, [5]) ? creep
   Fail: (10) lastX(6, [4, 5]) ? creep
   Fail: (9) lastX(6, [3, 4, 5]) ? creep
   Fail: (8) lastX(6, [2, 3, 4, 5]) ? creep
   Fail: (7) lastX(6, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) ? creep
false.
```

Comment: It is more clear now, thank you. but I don't understand why with `lastY` version, there is a call with an empty list, whereas there isn't such call with `lastX`. I think the clue is to find out which predicate is called when there is only one element, is it the one with one argument, or the one that has recursivity.

Comment: First of all look at function, what happens in first version? 
First predicate in both cases checks if there is only one element and if it is similar to element that you are looking for.

Second predicate cuts head and enters recursively. 
1st example: Second predicate is executing when there is at least 2 elements, any element and end of list symbol ([]). (Now look at trace)
2nd example: Similar to first one it executs when there are at least 3 elements, so at least it will execute recursively with [lastElement,[]]. (Look at trace again).

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on what you measure.  Apparently your teacher does what @Armatorix does in his answer, and simply counts invocations of last/2.  But in practice, your teacher's version will be slower on probably all Prolog systems, even significantly slower:

```
% Simple version:
?- length(Xs,10000000), time(last(X,Xs)).
% 10,000,000 inferences, 0.852 CPU in 0.852 seconds (100% CPU, 11735202 Lips)

% "Optimized" version
?- length(Xs,10000000), time(last(X,Xs)).
% 9,999,999 inferences, 4.436 CPU in 4.437 seconds (100% CPU, 2254074 Lips)
```

To understand why, you have to realize that the "optimized" version is syntactic sugar for

```
last(X,[X]).
last(X,[_,Y|L]):-
   YL = [Y|L],    % this takes time!
   last(X,YL).
```